# Does double.IsInfinity(value) cover double.IsPositiveInfinity(value) and double.IsNegativeInfinity(value))?

Tags: c#

**Background:**

I am pulling data from CSV files and writing it a database.
This runs extremely often and I'm trying to look at this from an efficiency point of view.

**Question:**

Is `double.IsPositiveInfinity(value) || double.IsNegativeInfinity(value)` redundant in the following code when trying to throw out infinite values?

**Code:**

```
foreach (var word in lineWords)
{
    double value;
    if (!double.TryParse(word, out value) || 
        double.IsNaN(value) || 
        double.IsInfinity(value) || 
        double.IsPositiveInfinity(value) || 
        double.IsNegativeInfinity(value))
    {
        continue;
    }

    //Store value
    ...
}
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure it would considering there is one for plain inf, +inf, and -inf. The RefSrc is the only way to tell though.

Comment: Wouldn't it have been trivial to check this for yourself?

Comment: [The documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.double.isinfinity.aspx) answers this already, does it not?

Comment: @hvd: Yup, I was just thinking that too. "Returns a value indicating whether the specified number evaluates to negative or positive infinity"

Comment: Embarassingly, the documentation couldn't be anymore clear.  Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, the extra checks are redundant. As noted on MSDN for [Double.IsInfinity](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.double.isinfinity.aspx):

> Returns a value indicating whether the specified number evaluates to negative or positive infinity

Comment: What about quibits? They could be both positive _and_ negative **at the same time**.